# Why do I get a program crash for large values but not small values for my program?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Why do I get a program crash for large values but not small values for my program? If I input 1-3 the program does what it is supposed to but when I enter a number greater than that the program crashes and/or does not complete? Is it something to do with a pointer error or the way I've referenced something? I'm unsure so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getData (int size, int *Arr){

    cout << "\n\nEnter integer data one line at a time\n" << endl ;

    for (int i=0; i < size; i++){
        cin >> Arr[i];
    }
}

void findMinAndMax(int array[], int size, int *min, int *max) {

    int smallest = array[0];
    int largest = array[0];

    *min = smallest;
    *max = largest;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > *max){
                *max = array[i];
                cout << "Max Value (loop): " << *max << endl;
            }
            if (array[i] < *min){
                *min = array[i];
                cout << "Min Value (loop): " << *max << endl;
            }
        }

    // testing code
    cout << "Min Value: " << *min << endl;
    cout << "Max Value: " << *max << endl;

}

int *makeFrequency (int data[], int dSize, int *minDataValue, int *maxDataValue) {

    cout << "Min Value Pre: " << *minDataValue << endl;// testing code
    cout << "Max Value Pre: " << *maxDataValue << endl;// testing code
    findMinAndMax(data, dSize, minDataValue, maxDataValue);
    cout << "Min Value Post: " << *minDataValue << endl; // testing code
    cout << "Max Value Post: " << *maxDataValue << endl;// testing code


    int fSize = *minDataValue + *maxDataValue;

    cout << "fSize: " << fSize << endl; // testing code

    int *frequency;
    frequency = new int [fSize];

    // if frequency is 0, end
    if (frequency == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    // set all elements to 0 in array frequency
    for (int i = 0; i <= fSize; i++) {
        frequency[i] = 0;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= dSize; i++) {
        int j = data[i] - (*minDataValue) + 1;
        frequency[j] = frequency[j] + 1;
    }

    return frequency;
}

void makeHistogram (int *freq, int min, int max ){

    cout << "Frequency Value HISTOGRAM: " << *freq << endl;

    cout << "\n\n\n ----------- Histogram ----------------\n" << endl;

    int size = min + max;
    cout << "Size Value HISTOGRAM: " << size << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        if (freq[i] > 0) {

            cout << "\n" << min + i - 1 << ": ";

            for (int j = 0; j < freq[i]; j++) {
                cout << '*';
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

int main() {

    int dSize;
    int *ArrayOfInts;

    cout << "How many data values? ";
    cin >> dSize;

    ArrayOfInts = new int [dSize];

    getData(dSize, ArrayOfInts);


    int *frequency, min, max;

    frequency = makeFrequency(ArrayOfInts, dSize, &min, &max);

    if (frequency == 0) return -1;

    cout << "Min Value MAIN: " << min << endl; // testing code
    cout << "Max Value MAIN: " << max << endl; // testing code
    cout << "Frequency Value MAIN: " << *frequency << endl;

    makeHistogram(frequency, min, max);


    delete [] frequency;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line is the crash happening on?

Comment: Because your zero-length array only overwrites something that you later need when you get to "large enough" values?

Comment: @Barmar In the makeFrequency function, just after the last cout statement I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place where you have undefined behaviour which can cause crashes:

here you allocate `fSize` elements:

```
frequency = new int [fSize];
```

later you iterate it until `fSize`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= fSize; i++) {
```

you should change to `i < fSize`, because there is no fSize element in your array. And the same problem with `i <= dSize` later on. Should be `i < dSize`.

btw. I dont see why only large values should cause crashes in your code, maybe this is just UB.

Comment: That was it! Not crashing anymore! Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasBall There are other problems, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `fSize` incorrectly. It should be the difference between the maximum and minimum values, not the sum of them. Otherwise, if you have negative numbers in your list, the `frequency` array will be too small. And if absolute value of any of the negative numbers is larger than the highest number, `fSize` will be negative, which is not valid for the size of an array.

Then you need to add 1 to include both endpoints. So it should be:

```
int fSize = *maxDataValue - *minDataValue + 1;
```

Then, as the other answer pointed out, you need to fix your `for` loops. When the size of an array is `N`, the array indexes from from `0` to `N-1`. So it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fSize; i++) {
```

using `<` as the loop test, not `<=`. If you try to write outside an array, you invoke undefined behavior, so anything can happen -- if you're lucky you get a crash, but that's not guaranteed.

You have a similar problem when you assign to `frequency`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dSize; i++) {
    int j = data[i] - (*minDataValue) + 1;
    frequency[j] = frequency[j] + 1;
}
```

There's no need to add `1` when subtracting `*minDataValue`, and doing so will cause you to go outside the array when `data[i]` is the maximum.

Comment: Oh okay, I see now, I didn't realize I was setting fSize incorrectly. Thank you!

Comment: You wouldn't notice the problem if all the inputs are positive, because this will make `frequency` larger than necessary. But if there are any negative numbers in the list, it's too small.